# Correct way to reassign value to variables that were created using destructuring? (Array destructuring)

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm just being introduced to destructuring (n00b) and have been following along with a course on frontend masters. The way it's presented is as follows:

```
let [firstVar, secondVar] = ["firstValue", "secondValue"]
```

Which makes sense. I can (and have) verified that `firstVar` gets the value `"firstValue"` and `secondVar` gets the value `"secondValue"`.

What is confusing is that I cannot seem to reassign the values stored in these variables.  I've used both `const` and `let` (in the manner shown above) and attempted to reassign the variables.  Where I have declared the variables using `const` no error is thrown.  If I'm playing around in the browser console, I get something like this:

```js
const [firstThing, secondThing] = ["first value", "second value"] 
console.log(firstThing) // expected output: first value
firstThing = "some new thing" 
console.log(firstThing) // expected output: first value
```

A screenshot of this behavior in FireFox Console (I navigated to about:blank to make sure that no old variables were in memory):
[image: Behavior in firefox console]

Again, no error is thrown (which I would normally expect when trying to reassign to a `const` variable.

If I do the following, I get behavior that I would expect:

```
[firstThing] = ["some new value"]
// TypeError: invalid assignment to const 'firstThing'
```

When the destructuring is done using `let`, I am able to (seemingly) re-assign value using similar syntax (enclosing the variable and the new value in brackets).

Edit:
People are showing that they are unable to reproduce the issue when running the code as shown in their browser. I didn't play with this originally in a Node REPL but doing so produces behavior that would be expected (attempting to reassign to a `const` var throws an error, `let` variables are fine with reassignment).  At this point I'm just curious why this behavior is not the same in my browser.  I'm using version 64.0.2.

To try and figure this out I skimmed the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment

Neither seemed to touch on the issue of re-assigning values to variables (or objects) that are created using destructuring.  Is the way that I'm approaching it technically correct?  I'm also starting to be introduced to garbage collection etc. (which I have only the briefest introduction to) and so I wonder if the reassignment "technique" I'm using is creating a bunch of stuff that doesn't get garbage collected or creates weird pointers etc. that might cause issues later on down the road.

Comment: unable to reproduce your problem, assignment works when i use let

Comment: How is that from the Firefox console? My browser doesn't do it. I get a TypeError when assigning the second time.

Comment: Hmm when I run it in a node REPL it behaves as you are describing it, as well as how I would normally expect it to. But it behaves differently in the browser console.

Comment: @VLAZ I can post a screencap if you don't believe me.

Comment: The ONLY explanation is that the second `firstThing` is *not the same as the first*. For example, if one of the letters was actually a letter from a different alphabet but looks like the English/Latin letter. Then you'd be assigning to a *new* variable that is an implied global and it's not actually the constant. Only then would you get this behaviour.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for at least contributing something that goes towards answering my question this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it was something weird in FireFox. I just updated to 65.0 and this behavior is no longer occurring.

Answer (score -1):

> no error is thrown (which I would normally expect when trying to reassign to a const variable.

I'm unable to reproduce. I see an error when running that code: "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."

```js
const [firstThing, secondThing] = ["first value", "second value"] 
console.log(firstThing) // expected output: first value
firstThing = "some new thing" 
console.log(firstThing) // expected output: first value
```

And if i use `let`, it allows me to reassign.

```js
let [firstThing, secondThing] = ["first value", "second value"] 
console.log(firstThing) // expected output: first value
firstThing = "some new thing" 
console.log(firstThing) // expected output: first value
```

Also unable to reproduce in firefox's console:

[image]

It's a bit tough to diagnose what the difference is in your environment as compared to ours. Maybe a different browser version, maybe a plugin, who knows. In any event, the code you posted just substituting in let instead of const is the correct way to reassign variables.

Comment: I will post a screenshot of the behavior in a moment.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you - it's behaving this way in my browser when I run it as shown, and I'm fairly certain that I don't have any hidden globals or anything (as in I navigated to a new blank page before running anything).

Comment: It's a bit tough to diagnose what the difference is in your environment as compared to mine and VLAZ's. Maybe a different browser version, maybe a plugin, who knows. In any event, the code you posted just substituting in `let` instead of `const` is the correct way to reassign variables.

Comment: Pending another answer this will have to suffice. Thank you for taking a look. I would have been confused as to why you'd have to treat the variables differently just because they were created using destructuring. Again, the behavior is consistent with my expectations when I run it in a node repl but now I'm curious as to why firefox is behaving how it is for me at the moment.